# Guardar archivos en diferentes carpetas , Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy guardando un archivo pdf de la siguiente forma:

```
if ($request->hasFile('tCertificado')) {
    foreach ($request -> tCertificado as $certificado) {
      $path_certificado = $certificado -> store('local');
    }
}
```

Entonces los archivos se guardan en el folder **storage/app/local**.
Pero lo que quiero es guardar dicho certificado de la siguiente forma:

Mi archivo: **micertificado.pdf**

Guardándose en **storage/app/local** de la siguiente forma:

storage/app/local/**NOMBRE_USUARIO**/micertificado**_280420200130**.pdf

Donde **NOMBRE_USUARIO** es el valor de un input text que se envía junto con las imágenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede utilizar la función [storeAs()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-uploads) para generar el nombre y almacenar en la carpeta que desea.

Para añadir una nueva carpeta bastaría con añadir a la ruta. `local/otracarpeta/otrasubcarpeta`

*(Para el ejemplo utilizaré variables estáticas que tendría que reemplazar con sus inputs)*

```
 $numero= '280420200130';
 $user = 'NOMBRE_USUARIO';

 $certificado->storeAs("local/$user",
           ('micertificado_'.$numero.'.'. $request->file('avatar')->extension()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar el **facade Storage**

Quedaría de esta manera tu método.

```
public function storageFiles(FormRequest $request)
{
   foreach ($request -> tCertificado as $certificado) {
       \Storage::disk()
          ->put(
           'local/'.$request->NOMBRE_USUARIO.'/micertificado_'.rand(100000, 999999)).'.pdf', 
            $certificado
          );
    }

}
```

> FormRequest este es el archivo donde aras las validaciones lo creas con: **php artisan make:request name_file** puedes buscarlo en la documentación de laravel si no sabes bien que hace.

Lo que hace el facade de storage es precisamente facilitar el guardar y recuperar archivos del storage o de los discos.

Solo debes de verificar que tenga los permisos adecuados para las tareas que quieres hacer y que este bien configurado.

Igual esta en la documentación de laravel.